# How can i unmount a functional component from DOM on click of a Button

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components, unmount

I would like to "Unmount a simple Functional Component" from the DOM. I searched a lot and saw most of the tutorials are based on Class Components and I did'nt see any simple example on it. My requirement is Unmounting a Functional component from the DOM on click on a button. Following is the component with the button which i likes to unmount when click on it. Hopes someone can help me to do it. Thanks in Advance !

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {
 return (
    <div className='app-component'>
      <h2 className="h2">App Component</h2>
      <button>Unmount This Component</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: You can conditional render your component based on a state in parent component. On click of a button make the state `falsy` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to unmount a component then you can use conditional rendering where you can declare state in parent component and based on the state you can mount or unmount component as:

This is the parent component from where you want to `mount` or `unmount`

[`CODESANDBOX DEMO`](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-grass-wh8rjc?file=/src/App.js)

> If you want to toggle component once then you can do the following because there is only one way to change state i.e from `Test` component. If you `unmount` this component there is no way to `mount` it again. So you can also declare button in `App` component from where you can `mount` or `unmount` on click of a button. [`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-star-ez5r56?file=/src/App.js)

**`Parent component`**

```
export default function App() {
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(true);  // STATE
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isShowing && <Test setIsShowing={setIsShowing} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**`Child component`**

```
function Test({ setIsShowing }) {
  function unmountComponent() {
    setIsShowing(false);
  }
  return (
    <div className="app-component">
      <h2 className="h2">App Component</h2>
      <button onClick={unmountComponent}>Unmount This Component</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Decpk, Thank you for giving me a detailed solution on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use state flag for removing element like this:

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {
const [flag,setFlage]=useState(true);
 return (
    <div className='app-component'>
      {flag?<h2 className="h2">App Component</h2>:null}
      <button onClick={()=>setFlag(!flage)} >Unmount This Component</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Hi Arash Ghazi, Thanks for giving me the Thread of doing my requirement.